# I have also seen Silhouettes of weedle and seedot, sableye. I already have these

Tags: pokemon-go

In the nearby list you can see sableye is a silhouette I have that one already and don't understand why these pokemon are  up like this.

[image: silhouette]

Comment: All those Pokemon were recently introduced as Shadow Pokemon. The question and answer in Wondercricket's link apply exactly to these Pokemon. As per the answer given in the above link, this causes the aforementioned Pokemon to be coded as form "Normal" instead of without a form. This causes the silhouette to appear as new despite already having the Pokemon.